# EXC_BAD_ACCESS when allocating an NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, game-center

This is a bit of a weird one.

In my code, I have this line:

```
    NSMutableArray *unresolvedPlayers = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:3];
```

This seems like a perfectly valid line.  I crashed on this line with this stack trace (I have replaced my app name with xxxxxxxxx):

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0xc158f710
Triggered by Thread:  7

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3870d648 syscall_thread_switch + 8
1   libsystem_platform.dylib        0x3879a79a _os_lock_handoff_lock_slow + 74
2   libsystem_malloc.dylib          0x38748ece szone_malloc_should_clear + 50
3   libsystem_malloc.dylib          0x3874c444 malloc_zone_calloc + 92
4   libsystem_malloc.dylib          0x3874c3d2 calloc + 46
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x380c8414 class_createInstance + 36
6   CoreFoundation                  0x2a5773d0 __CFAllocateObject2 + 8
7   CoreFoundation                  0x2a48c86a +[__NSArrayM __new:::::] + 38
8   CoreFoundation                  0x2a48fd7c -[__NSPlaceholderArray initWithCapacity:] + 100
9   CoreFoundation                  0x2a497e88 +[NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:] + 36
10  xxxxxxxxxx                      0x001730f4 -[HostManager setHost:timestamp:] (HostManager.m:703)
11  xxxxxxxxxx                      0x0016ff10 -[HostManager initSessionFromInvitation:] (HostManager.m:46)
12  xxxxxxxxxx                      0x000ea68e -[NetworkController updateWithMatch:] (NetworkController.m:894)
13  xxxxxxxxxx                      0x000ea418 __72-[NetworkController invitePlayersToMatch:playerGroup:completionHandler:]_block_invoke544 (NetworkController.m:844)
14  GameCenterFoundation            0x31263936 __72-[GKMatchmaker invitePlayersWithRequest:serverHosted:completionHandler:]_block_invoke601 + 42
15  libdispatch.dylib               0x38620420 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 8
16  libdispatch.dylib               0x3862040c _dispatch_client_callout + 20
17  libdispatch.dylib               0x3862b1b0 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF$VARIANT$mp + 708
18  CoreFoundation                  0x2a53762c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 4
19  CoreFoundation                  0x2a535d4c __CFRunLoopRun + 1508
20  CoreFoundation                  0x2a482b2c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 472
21  CoreFoundation                  0x2a48293e CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
22  GraphicsServices                0x3183904c GSEventRunModal + 132
23  UIKit                           0x2da786ec UIApplicationMain + 1436
24  xxxxxxxxxx                      0x000503b2 main (main.m:16)
25  libdyld.dylib                   0x3865baac start + 0
```

How is it possible that my memory has gotten corrupted up to this point that allocating a new NSMutableArray would cause this to happen?  I'm not even sure where to start with debugging this one.  I am not sure this is easily reproducible.

As a side note, it happened when inviting nearby players to a realtime GameCenter match.

**EDIT:**  I just realized this is crashing on Thread 7.  This is what Thread 7 looks like:

```
Thread 7 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.default-qos
Thread 7 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x380cbf66 objc_msgSend + 6
1   GameCenterFoundation            0x31285efc -[GKMatchmaker(Nearby) inviteAnyNearbyPlayersWithRequest:] + 960
2   GameCenterFoundation            0x312636a8 __72-[GKMatchmaker invitePlayersWithRequest:serverHosted:completionHandler:]_block_invoke + 256
3   GameCenterFoundation            0x3129ae92 __39-[GKDispatchGroup notifyOnQueue:block:]_block_invoke44 + 10
4   libdispatch.dylib               0x38620420 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 8
5   libdispatch.dylib               0x3862c2d6 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 846
6   libdispatch.dylib               0x3862d1f6 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 102
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3879de22 _pthread_wqthread + 666
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3879db74 start_wqthread + 4
```

So, this is probably a bug with GameCenter.

Comment: just because it crashes in framework code doesn't mean it's the framework's fault. post your nearby players code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crash in `objc_msgSend` can indicate that message destination object is deallocated already. Try to [enable zombie objects](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-scheme_editor/Articles/SchemeDiagnostics.html) and keep your eyes on logs.